# What's up with the Review Audits -- I believe this is incorrect

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

I was trying to make a dent in the VTC queue, and came across this question.

[Phonegap 3.0.0 + Android always wants to use remote environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274464/phonegap-3-0-0-android-always-wants-to-use-remote-environment)

I read it through, and VTC - Unclear, as there was no question.  In fact, I would put this up as a textbook example of VTC-Unclear.

All of a sudden, I get a surprise audit -- You Failed -- ...

No, I didn't fail. Audit failed.

Comment: Guess they want you to open up all questions in a new tab, downvote it and them come back to judging it

Comment: There's an implied question there... "can I get it to stop attempting to sign me in"

Comment: +1 for _"Audit failed"_.

Comment: Anyways, can we have a link to the _audit_, not the question?

Comment: I have to agree with the ben here. Despite the lack of an explicit question in that particular [instance/revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18274464/2), this sentence "*it seems as if it's possible to use the local environment as well*" gave me the impression that the OP was trying to figure out how to get phonegap to use a local environment.

Answer (score 9):

This is a question about [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The author is encountering several problems when attempting to use them, which he describes in the question along with the specific errors returned by the tools.

Yes, there were some minor issues with the grammar and formatting - if you felt they made the question unacceptable, you could have clicked the "edit" button and passed the audit that way too...

Answer (score 3):

The audits are selected by finding questions with no flags, no votes to close, no downvotes, at least five upvotes, and a handful of other criteria.  It assumes that if those criteria are met, the question shouldn't be closed.

Occasionally that is incorrect because people fail to downvote/flag/vote to close questions that should indeed be closed.

To prevent this particular question from ever being an audit again, if you indeed feel that it should be closed, just downvote or vote to close (FYI, this has already happened for this particular question).

Comment: There's no reason to vote to close this question. The audit was valid in this case.